# how to open worksheet by passing value into variable in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to open worksheet by taking value from one cell and concate the desire file name but it shows error : object variable or with block variable not set
i'm using following code :
where "123.xlsx" is name of workbook that i want to open .

```
Dim output_path As Workbook
dim xlwkbrpt1  as workbook
output_path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("F14").Value
Set xlwkbrpt1 = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(output_path & "\" & "123.xlsx")
```

Comment: Why is `output_path` a Workbook? Shouldn't it be a string? Also, print `output_path & "\" & "123.xlsx"` just before executing the last statement and see what the `Open` method is trying to open.

Comment: @FDavidov it shows same error even i change the datatype

Comment: Please add a print of the parameter to `xlApp.Workbooks.Open`just before the invocation and append the result to your question.

Comment: By the way, I see that your comment to the answer by bzimor states that the solution does nor work, but the answer is flagged as resolving the issue. So is the issue solved or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared variable `output_path` with wrong type. Try this:

```
Dim output_path As String
Dim xlwkbrpt1  As Workbook
output_path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("F14").Value
Set xlwkbrpt1 = Workbooks.Open(output_path & "\" & "123.xls")
```

Comment: I apllied your code with correction of dattype but it's still showing same error